# Get a list of all unique tags used within a set of entities

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I've got two models: `Group` and `Item`. An `Item` has a list of tags and belongs to a `Group`.

```python
class Group(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Item(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    tags = db.StringListProperty()
    group = db.ReferenceProperty(Group)
```

So far, typical actions are adding a tag to an `Item`, removing a tag from an `Item`, and showing all `Item`s matching a given `Group` and tag.

**What's a good way for getting a list of all unique tags used within a `Group`?**

Ideally I'd like to have a property in `Group` that reflects the tags used:

```python
class Group(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    aggregated_tags = db.StringListProperty()
```

It would be even better if this included the number of `Item`s that have this tag.

Permanent consistency is not a requirement, i.e. it is fine if the aggregated list of tags does not match the actual list of tags in use, as long as they become consistent eventually.

`Item` and `Group` are not in the same entity group, so I can't have a transaction that updates the `Item` and the `Group` at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to maintain it yourself. Update the list of tags whenever you add or remove one from an item. You can do this in a task queue task if you want to do it asynchronously.

Alternatively, you could write a mapreduce that you run periodically that recalculates the tag set for every group - in fact, this is pretty much a classic use-case for mapreduce.